# Disable markdown or automatically escape formatting characters in @user references

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, comment-replies

I noticed that in certain cases, if a username has a particular sequence of characters, then posting an `@user` reference in the comments can cause some unexpected formatting. For example:

```
@Some-_User_ Hello World!
```

Will be rendered as:

> @Some-*User* Hello World!

Can we disable markdown formatting in `@user` references in the comments? Or perhaps change the automatic user selection box to insert `\` where necessary (in the same way that it automatically removes spaces)? In other words, it would default to something like this:

```
@Some-\_User_ Hello World!
```

Which will be rendered as:

> @Some-_User_ Hello World!

<sub>[Here is the specific case that prompted me to post this question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148001/force-100-cpu-usage-on-server#comment39148938_25148001)</sub>

Comment: Or folks could just not use underscores in their names. Who do you think you are, underscore_named_user? A_C_MACRO?! Use dashes or CaseTransitions or even (the horror!) *spaces!*

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah in this case it seems to require a dash and an underscore (basically a `\b` I think). I don't think any of those examples would cause a problem or you'd see this a lot more.